# I want to use Meteor.setInterval() to update a time-template, it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to update my time-function with the Meteor.setInterval-command.

This is how my *.js-file looks like:

```
function uhrzeit() {
  var zeit = new Date();
  var std = zeit.getHours();
  var min = zeit.getMinutes();
  return std + ":" + min;
};

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.uhr.zeit = function() {
    Meteor.setInterval(uhrzeit, 1000); //Edit: Changed it to pass, not call the function.
    return uhrzeit();
  };
}
```

The template is not updated. It shows me the actual time once I update the page but doesn't update regularly. Or at least I doesnt change the time in HTML.

Comment: `Meteor.setInterval(uhrzeit, 1000);`  You want to pass the function, not its return value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function is not reactive. You need to set up a dependency, ensure your data function depend on it and update it periodically.

Also, data function is not a good place to call `setInterval`. It can be called many times and create many intervals, which is undesired. `created` is a better place for such things.

Also, make sure to clear all intervals you create. `destroyed` is a good place to do so.

Code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var zeitDep = new Deps.Dependency(); // !!!
  var zeitValue;
  var zeitInterval;

  function uhrzeit() {
    var zeit = new Date();
    var std = zeit.getHours();
    var min = zeit.getMinutes();
    zeitValue = std + ":" + min;
    zeitDep.changed(); // !!!
  };

  Template.uhr.created = function() {
    uhrzeit(); /* Call it once so that we'll have an initial value */
    zeitInterval = Meteor.setInterval(uhrzeit, 1000);
  };

  Template.uhr.zeit = function() {
    zeitDep.depend(); // !!!
    return zeitValue;
  };

  Template.uhr.destroyed = function() {
    Meteor.clearInterval(zeitInterval);
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be (note no `()` after `uhrzeit`):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.uhr.zeit = function() {
    Meteor.setInterval(uhrzeit, 1000);
    return uhrzeit();
  };
}
```

You should *pass* function rather than *call* function (adding `()` is effectively calling the function).

This `Meteor.setInterval(uhrzeit(), 1000);` will effectively be "call `<whatever is returned by uhrzeit>` every 1 second".

Comment: You solved my error-message. Though my template is not updated using this code. Any ideas?

Comment: The effect of `uhrzeit()` is simply returning `std + ":" + min` to nowhere. Its result is not assigned to anything. You might want to actually update something from `uhrzeit`.

Comment: I thought by calling the function again, it would pull a new Date again.

Comment: It will pull the date and get hours and minutes from it, but will not assign the result value `std+":"+min` to anything. I.e. every second this function will get the time and return it to void.

Comment: This is my html where it is returned to `<div id="clock">{{zeit}}</div>` As far as I understand it is not returned to void.

Comment: That's not really how it works here... in the function you're simply creating new variable `zeit` (`var zeit =...`) which will be visible _only_ within this function.

Comment: I am not trying to call the variable in html. {{zeit}} is a meteor-template. The template executes "return uhrzeit();", which returns std +":"+ min. So I thought by calling the function again it should update its std and min values and return them to the template. It happens once but is not updated after.

Comment: Still, this won't refresh anything. The `zeit` function has nothing reactive inside, calling `setInterval` will do nothing to refresh actual contents.

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    const VAR_TIME = 'now';

    Session.setDefault(VAR_TIME, new Date());

    Template.time.helpers({  // <---- HIGH IMPORTANCE
        now: function() {
            return Session.get(VAR_TIME);
        }
    });

    Meteor.setInterval(function tickUpdate() {

        var date = new Date();
        Session.set(VAR_TIME, date);
        console.log(Session.get(VAR_TIME));
    }, 1000);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>    
  {{> time}}
</body>
<template name="time">
  <p>The time now is: {{now}}</p>
</template>
```