# Auto update timeAgo value from submitted date

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

**EDIT: I think I should make things more obvious.

What I am trying to do is to make the function that displays the "time ago" from the submitted date of the post auto refresh every minute so that it stays relatively accurate even if the template is not re rendered.**

I'd like to auto update my timeago value in my template but it is not working.

I've tried to set up my code with a reactive function, based on the answer to a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933506)

Here's my code:

```
var timeAgoDep = new Deps.Dependency(); // !!!
var timeAgo;
var timeAgoInterval;

Template.postItem.created = function() {
    function getTimeago() {
        //var now = new Date();
        timeAgo = moment(this.submitted).twitter();
        timeAgoDep.changed(); // !!!
    };

    getTimeago(); /* Call it once so that we'll have an initial value */
    timeAgoInterval = Meteor.setInterval(getTimeago, 5000);
};

Template.postItem.posted = function() {
    timeAgoDep.depend(); // !!!
    return timeAgo;
};

Template.postItem.destroyed = function() {
    Meteor.clearInterval(timeAgoInterval);
};
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem comes from this.submitted because if I assign timeAgo = now for example, it will display the time and update like it's supposed to.

I also know that **moment(this.submitted).twitter()** works fine because when all I do is return it through a helper, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better way to do this is to just embrace Meteor's reactivity and render time-dependent values reactively. In your case, the problem is that you are invalidating the dependency once every 5 seconds **for each `postItem` rendered**, which will quickly turn into a huge mess.

See https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync for a package that provides reactive time variables on the client (and they are synced to server time too!) It's basically doing what you want, but in a cleaner way. (Disclaimer: I wrote this package.)

You can use moment in the same way to compute the actual string to display. For example, get rid of all the other stuff and just use

```
Template.postItem.posted = function() {
    return moment(this.submitted).from(TimeSync.serverTime());
}
```

The `moment().twitter()` extension doesn't seem like a good choice because it only uses the current client time and doesn't allow you to pass in a specific (i.e. server-synced) time or reactive value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not think you've understood my problem and I probably should've made it clearer.  
When a post is saved, its creation time is saved in the document in "submitted". So it never changes. And that's good: it should not change. But at the same time I have a function that wraps around that date and converts it into a timeago form. The problem, quite obvious now, is that that function is only being executed when the template is rendered and so the "time ago" quickly becomes inaccurrate, so I would like it to auto update, say, every minute.

Comment: @oliv23 I do believe I've perfectly understood your question. I'm suggesting you render the variable `timeago(currentTime - creationTime)`, where I'm suggesting to use a reactive value for `currentTime` that invalidates at regular intervals, resulting in automatic updates to the string. The library I linked to provides exactly that, and you can use moment to show time ago in the exact format you want.

Comment: Ahh Ok I understand. It does makes a lot more sense to have the timeago function depend on a reactive currentTime value. I took a look at the package and from what I understand, I would be using the serverTime() function for that but how do I tell it how often to update? I don't want real time "timeago", just updated every 60s.

Comment: @oliv23 That's something we could allow for in the library but it might be premature optimization at this point. Unless you have thousands of timeago values on your page, update computations are pretty fast with Blaze. Give it a try and take a look at the Chrome task manager. Just to be clear on my suggestion, take a look at the code above.

Comment: Yeah I guess I won't worry about it then. Might be something you would want to add to your package sometime though. Anyway, thanks for the code. I had actually started with that and it works but I ended up baking the TimeSync.serverTime directly into moment.twitter. That way I get both the reactivity and twitter syntax.